# Can we get the selecteditem in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, telerik

I have a delegate command for a button. I want is select a row in the radgridview then clicking the button to get the row information.

The view:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView Name="playersGrid" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" 
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Number}"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Country}"/>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

My ViewModel is

```
private object selectedItem;

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return this.selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.selectedItem)
            {
                this.selectedItem = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void Click_CreateButton(object param)
    {
        // get row selectedItem
    }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Hello, What row information do you want precisely?

Comment: @Alcruz, let's say anything of the row such as the first column value etc.`var x = this.SelectedItem;`

Comment: But what happen with using `this.SelectedItem;`, is it returning `null` ??

Comment: Yes, it is null. So I think that it is hard to get it from View Model. Should I switch on the code behind?

Comment: No, you shouldn't switch to code behind, I have done the same dozens of times, let's confirm you had everything in its place. Are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your viewmodel class?

Comment: @Alcruz, my ViewModel class inherited a base class. Base class inherited `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In the base class, we have  `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and the method `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Alcruz, the thing is that I don't really select the row even I click the row indicator. Not sure why, when I move away the row, the row is not highlighted at all. It is supposed to have an [orange color](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/selection/selecting-rows-and-cells-programmatically). When I move the mouse away, the color is gone as well.